# ELK : Store incomind data before Logstash process it

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Hey everyone I have incoming data from tcp and udp to Logstash. What I want to do is store that data before Logstash process it, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The source data is store in message field which is default in coming message

so you write a grok pattern to parsing the data is from the message field .

```
grok {        
          break_on_match => true
          match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logDate}%{GREEDYDATA:messages}"}
      }
```